# Pass javascript to php in modal window

Tags: php, javascript, variables

I am trying to pass a javascript variable to php in a modal window, all on the same page, which is edit.php. (I'll figure out how to do it with separate pages later). In the meanwhile, this javascript code works to pass the variable to the modal:

```
 <script type="application/javascript">
 $(document).on("click", ".open-EditRow", function () {
   var myGroupId = $(this).data('id');
   $(".modal-body #groupId").val( myGroupId );
 });
 </script>
```

In the modal window, here is the code I have been working with:

```
 <div class="modal hide fade" id="myEditModal">
 <div class="modal-body">
 <form class="well-small" action="" method="POST" id="modalForm" name="modalForm">
   <?php ********* code *********** ?>
 </form>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Inside the form is where I have my php code where I successfully retrieve the groupId from the javascript and where I am able to print it to the screen with an input tag.  Here is the code:

```
 <?php
   $id = "<input type=\"text\" name=\"groupId\" id=\"groupId\" value=\"\" />";
   echo "Group Id: " . $id;
   $sql = "SELECT mygroup FROM mytable WHERE pk_tId = '" . $id . "'";
   $result = mysql_query($sql);
   if(mysql_data_seek($result)){
     $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
   }
   else {
     echo "Cannot seek row: " . mysql_error() . "\n";
   }
 ?>
```

The sql statement cannot find $id in the database because $id is being printed as an input tag. How can I extract the groupId out of the input tag so that my sql statement will work?

Example, please. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You cannot do that via PHP... PHP is executed server side before you page is generated (and before JS can be executed...) You need to send GroupID variable via JS on requesting external page which contains your update statement.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is executed before your page is loaded.

You can do this via Ajax, when JS is triggered, by calling your PHP script and passing the `id` as a param:

```js
<script type="application/javascript">
 $(document).on("click", ".open-EditRow", function () {
   var myGroupId = $(this).data('id');
   $(".modal-body #groupId").val( myGroupId );

   // ajax call
   var url = "/path/to/script.php?id=" + myGroupId;
   $.get(url, function(data){
     // do something with the result         
   });
 });
<script>
```

You could also open the modal once you get the response and if there is an error don't open it and show an error message instead. But it depends on your use case.

**UPDATE**

Your PHP script looks basically like your code, except you get the `id` as param from the request. Try something like this:

```
<?php
   $id = $_GET['id']

   $sql = "SELECT mygroup FROM mytable WHERE `pk_tId`='$id'";
   $result = mysql_query($sql);
   if($result) {
     if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
       $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
       echo $row;
     }
     else {
       echo "Cannot seek row: " . mysql_error() . "\n";
     }
   }
   else {
     echo "Cannot seek row: " . mysql_error() . "\n";
   }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for providing an example. Testing.

Comment: I understand that I would need to put that in another folder in another file. Would you please provide an example of what the script.php page would like?

Answer (score 0):

I eventually added an onclick function to the modal a href and created a cookie which I grabbed once the modal was opened.  I used javascript to clear the cookie when I closed the modal.

Comment: You could improve your answer by adding actual code samples to it.